# SharePoint BDC Service error: Cannot connect to the LobSystem (External System)

Tags: sharepoint, bdc

Im new to SharePoint 2010. I created an External Content Type in SharePoint Designer using data from AdventureWorks database. After setting permissions for my ECT I created an External List and configuring my ECT as the datasource. When trying to access my External List in SharePoint I got an error message: "Cannot connect to the LobSystem (External System)"

A helpful response is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the login Users of sql server can view the data of external list of sharepoint site
If you want to see the external list data then add sharepoint users under SQL server
security\Logins